# Using Counter to create a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, counter, tokenize

I have an output of words which I would like to use to create a dictionary where keys = word; value = word's frequency

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import sys
import codecs
import re
import urllib, urllib2

import nltk  # Natural Language Processing

from nltk.corpus import stopwords # list of words
import string  # list(string.punctuation) - produces a list of punctuations
from collections import Counter  # optimized way to do this

#wordToken = ['happy', 'thursday', 'from', 'my', 'big', 'sweater', 'and', 'this', 'ART', '@', 'East', 'Village', ',', 'Manhattan', 'https', ':', '//t.co/5k8PUInmqK', 'RT', '@', 'MayorKev', ':', 'IM', 'SO', 'HYPEE', '@', 'calloutband', '@', 'FreakLikeBex', '#', 'Callout', '#', 'TheBitterEnd', '#', 'Manhattan', '#', 'Music']

# this is the output from wordToken = [token.encode('utf-8') for tweetL in tweetList for token in nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(tweetL)]

wordTokenLw = ' '.join(map(str, wordToken))
wordTokenLw = wordTokenLw.lower()

tweetD = {}

#c = Counter(wordTokenLw)

c = Counter(word.lower() for word in wordToken) # TRYING the suggested answer

#tweetD = dict(c.most_common())
tweetD = dict(c)

print tweetD
```

However, my output is completely wrong:

```
{'\x80': 2, 'j': 4, ' ': 192, '#': 21, "'": 1, '\xa6': 2, ',': 1, '/': 37, '.': 13, '1': 1, '0': 5, '3': 2, '2': 4, '5': 3, '7': 2, '9': 2, '8': 1, ';': 1, ':': 18, '@': 14, 'b': 17, 'a': 83, 'c': 36, '\xe2': 2, 'e': 63, 'd': 16, 'g': 10, 'f': 12, 'i': 37, 'h': 33, 'k': 12, '&': 1, 'm': 38, 'l': 22, 'o': 37, 'n': 49, 'q': 5, 'p': 33, 's': 32, 'r': 44, 'u': 20, 't': 104, 'w': 11, 'v': 14, 'y': 21, 'x': 8, 'z': 5}
```

I think the issue is with the way my dfile is formatted ( I used a space as a separator for join function). The reason I use JOIN function is to use lower() to get everything in lowercase. However, if there is a better way which will help my end result it would be awesome to hear about it.

This is a new area for me and truly appreciate your help!

The output after trying:

```
c = Counter(word.lower() for word in wordToken)

{'over': 1, 'hypee': 1, '//t.co/0\xe2\x80\xa6': 1, ',': 1, 'thursday': 1, 'day': 1, 'to': 2, 'dreams': 1, 'main': 1, '@': 14, 'automotive': 1, 'tbt': 1, 'positivital': 1, '2ma': 1, 'amp': 1, 'traveiplaces': 1, '//t.co/vmbal\xe2\x80\xa6': 1, '//t.co/c9ezuknraq': 1, 'motorcycles': 1, 'river': 1, 'view': 1, '//t.co/kpeunlzoyf': 1, 'art': 1, 'reillyhunter': 1, '//t.co/5pcxnzpwhw': 1, 'mayorkev': 1, 'rt': 5, '#': 21, 'pinterest': 1, 'away': 1, 'traveltuesday': 1, 'ice': 1, '//t.co/simhceefqy': 1, 'state': 1, 'fog': 1, ';': 1, '3d': 1, 'be': 1, 'run': 1, '//t.co/xrqaa7cb3e': 1, 'taevision': 1, 'by': 1, 'on': 1, 'livemusic': 1, 'bmwmotorradusa': 1, 'taking': 1, 'calloutband': 1, 'jersey': 1, 'uber': 1, 'bell': 1, 'freaklikebex': 1, 'village': 1, '.': 1, 'from': 2, '//t.co/5k8puinmqk': 1, '//t.co/gappxrvuql': 1, '&': 1, '500px': 1, 'sweater': 1, 'callout': 1, 'next': 1, 'appears': 1, 'music': 1, 'https': 5, ':': 18, 'happy': 1, 'park': 1, 'mercedesbenz': 1, 'amcafee': 1, 'foggy': 1, 'east': 2, '7pm': 1, 'this': 2, 'of': 1, 'taxis': 1, 'my': 1, 'and': 2, 'bridge': 1, 'centralpark': 1, '//t.co/ujdzsywt0u': 1, 'toughrides': 1, '10/22': 1, 'am': 1, 'thebitterend': 1, 'bmwmotorrad': 1, 'im': 1, 'at': 2, 'in': 3, 'cream': 1, 'nj': 1, '//t.co/hnxktmvrsc': 1, 'ny': 2, 'big': 1, 'nyc': 3, 'rides': 1, 'manhattan': 10, 'nice': 1, 'week': 1, 'blue': 1, 'http': 7, 'effect': 1, 'paleteria': 1, "'m": 1, 'a': 1, '//t.co/ucgfcwp9j2': 1, 'i': 2, 'so': 1, 'bmw': 1}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you join into a single string again, the `Counter` starts counting *letters* instead of words (since you're giving it an iterable of letters). Instead, you should make a `Counter` directly from the `wordToken` list; you can use a generator expression to call `lower` on each item as you put it in the counter:

```
c = Counter(word.lower() for word in wordToken)
```

Comment: I tried this. A question first: will this convert everything to a lower case or it is done temporarily to do the Counter?  The output makes a lot more sense but is a bit weird. I placed in the code section for the question. There seems to be practically all words one time only. It is possible but something does not feel right, imho

Comment: This will just lowercase the words going into the Counter. If you want to lower everything, just change your initial list comprehension to be `token.encode(..).lower()`.

Answer (score 1):

It is one of the common mistakes when dealing with strings. Strings are iterable in Python and sometimes when a function takes an iterable and we end up giving strings, we find the function acting on the elements of the string, which are the chars constituting the string.

```
class collections.Counter([iterable-or-mapping])
```

In you case, you should simply do the counter on the `wordToken` like this.

```
Counter(map(lambda w: w.lower(), wordToken)
```

Comment: awesome! thank you for your great explanation! Actually it gives a syntax error for the next line for some reason ( I also tried changing w for word but still the error)